# How to create an Instance of an Object via RestController while not passing all the fields of the constructor via RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have an object defined as:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Task {
    @Id
    @Getter @Setter private Integer id;
    @Getter @Setter private String text;
    @Getter @Setter private Boolean isDone = Boolean.FALSE;

    public Task(int id, String text){
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.isDone = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

If I pass in {
    "id:":1,
    "text":"buy juice"
} as request body, RestController can create an instance of task. However I don't want to pass id as a field in my request body. How do I handle that?

Comment: You do not have to pass the value for `id` as you have defined strategy for id as `strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, it will be automatically created while saving in DB

Comment: You should not set `id` since it is marked as `@GeneratedValue`. Just call the no-args constructor, set `text` and (if necessary) `isDone` and persist the entity. After the transaction is closed, the `id` will be set.

Comment: `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` is subjected to type of database you are using. for example, MySQL doesn't have sequences, Oracle DB has. For MySql, `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` works pretty well.

Comment: Edited the code. I donot have `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` yet. Thus, passing id in request body and it is working fine. However, I now want to implement id being generated automatically and am not able to figure out, how.

Comment: This is how I want to receive the body: `public Task addTask(@RequestBody Task task)`

Comment: As described abouve, annotate `id` with `@GeneratedValue` to let the database generate the `id`. Remember that the change is only guaranteed to be visible after the transaction has been closed or flushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL, change your entity as below

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter 
@Setter 
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String text;
    private Boolean isDone = Boolean.FALSE;

    public Task(int id, String text){
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.isDone = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

and then your request would change to simply passing text: `{"text":"buy juice" }`

JPA's save would now work as following

1. If id is present in the request, it will assume entity exists and update it
2. If id is not present in the request, it will create a new row in DB and auto-assign id

**P.S.** - Depending on what DB you have, you can choose optimal id generation strategy for that DB. For example, identity-based generation works well with MySQL, sequence-based generation works well with Oracle db.

Comment: Works. Thanks.
One change to your code snippet: `id` is of type Long. You need to do `this.id = (long)id;`